# Order of keyword arguments and backward compatibility

Tags: python

If the authors of the library say that all subversions of the current major version remain backward compatible, does that mean that the signatures of functions are fixed? (i.e. no positional arguments would be added, the order of keyword arguments in functions are fixed, and additional keyword arguments will be added just at the end of the signature?)

Or does the Python community not have an agreement in this question (e.g. keyword arguments can be added not just in the end)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

backward compatibility is a pretty well defined promise:

you can update the library, and existing code will continue to function the same way as it did before, without requiring any adaptations.

changing the position of positional (i.e. non-keyword-only) args, will in most cases alter the functionality of existing code, so it breaks the promise.

[keyword-only](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) arguments can of course be added to any position without altering behavior of existing code.

Answer (score 2):

Backwards compatibility means updated lib can't break the already working code - so if signature changes, it has to keep the already existing positional arguments and keyword-only arguments. This means the new arguments can be added - because if the default value is provided, you don't have to specify it in the call!

Let's say this is our lib1.0 function:

```
def fun(a, b, c, *, k):
    pass
```

This means we have 3 positional arguments (can be provided using keywords) and one keyword-only (always has to be provided as a keyword) argument.

We can call it as `fun(1,2,3,k=4)` (positional as positional) or `fun(k=4,a=1,b=2,c=3)` (all as keyword).

When we update our library, e.g. to add more customisation, we can't break those calls. But if we add default values, they will still work:

Our lib1.1:

```
def fun(a, b, c, d=0, *, k, k2=None):
    pass
```

### So to answer your questions:

> (i.e. no positional arguments would be added,

No. New positional arguments are possible but need to have a default value (or be `*args`).

> the order of keyword arguments in functions are fixed,

No. Keyword-only arguments are always passed with their name, so the order can be any.

New keyword-only arguments need to have a default value (to not break compatibility) but can placed between other keyword-only arguments.

```
#lib1.2 version with new keyword-only value mixed:
def fun(a, b, c, d=0, *, new_keyword="look at me!", k, k2=None):
    pass
```

> > and additional keyword arguments will be added just at the end of the signature?)

The general rule is that arguments without a default value are usually before the ones with it.

So our new keyword argument can be at the end, but can be also between other keyword arguments with default values... or if you don't care about the style as much, it can be like in 1.2 above, where our new keyword was added *before* any other keyword arguments!